# mysql trigger that updates only one specific record/row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this table in mysql db:

| ID | ... | CREATE_DATE | UPDATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 7 | Cell8 |

I need two triggers which have to behave like this:

1. when inserting a new row, create_date has to be instanced with current_timestamp
2. when updating a a row, the field update_date of this one has to be updated with current_timestamp

Could someone help me please?

I know trigger have "for each row " operations but I don't know how to act on a single row

Comment: 'don't know how to act on a single row' should possibly read 'don't know how to act on a single COLUMN'

Comment: Neither of this requires a trigger, just a proper default value....